# Protractor - Return the operating system

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, webdriver, protractor

Does anyone know how to return the operating system using Protractor?

A little context: I need to press some keys (I think I'll be using action sequence to do so) but as the keyboard is different for MAC and PC, I think I need an if statement detecting which OS I'm running the tests on. If anyone knows a better way to do this? It's further compounded by the keys being relatively unusual (fn + F10) on MAC and just F10 on PC.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protractor runs on node, so you can use the inbuilt node variable [`process.platform`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform).

Comment: Thank-you. One got-cha, the result when on a mac is 'darwin'.

Comment: One things is the machine from where you run `protractor` cli and another is the browser in which the tests run, given selenium can be located far away are you sure `process.platform` is what you need?

Comment: Hi elgalu, What do you mean by far away? Ideally I want the machine which the tests are running on.

Comment: I think LeoGallucci means if protractor's node environment are not running on the same as the box with selenium and the browser this is more common in more complicated CI environments. 

I have the same question in that case. First I thought to check capabilities object but don't see anything obvious there. The only other thing I can think at the moment is something with `browser.executeScript ` and User Agent
[Protractor Documentation](https://github.com/alecxe/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-interact-directly-with-the-javascript-running-in-my-app)